# With a DrawerLayout, how can I close the app on pressing Back no matter which screen is active?

Tags: java, android

I'm using a DrawerLayout for the navigation of my app:

Taking this menu for the example:

[image]

I'd like the Home button to launch the HomeActivity and so on. But clearing the activity stack, that is: If I press People, then Photos, then Locations and then the back button, the app should close. I'm trying intent flags when launching the activities but I always get the same behaviour: **People->Photos->Location->Back** goes to Photos instead closing the app

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think u should Consider using Fragment For HOme,People,Photos,Location etc then on Back Press clear Fragment stack and finish activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you said that "If I press People, then Photos, then Locations and then the back button, the app should close".

For achieve that you should user Fragment for Home,People,Location and Photos etc.
and when you press back button of Device you can clear Fragment back stack and finish activity.

Comment: Yes, but due the activity scheme they need to be in diferent activities

Comment: You mean to said that you have Implement DrawerLayout in your baseActivity which use to Show People,Photos,Location.

Comment: I think in you case as you have use Activity for all your menu in DrawLayout ,You should declare your Home Activity as singleTask and When user press back from Location can Home Activity will Clear FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and finish Home Activity from onNewIntent Method.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code may help you. When you press Back button of a device it will close the application.

In MainActivity.java,

```
public void SelectItem(int possition) 
{

            //Using Fragment here
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    switch (possition) 
    {

           //Can use Fragment for Home,People,Location and Photos etc. and when you press back button of Device you can clear Fragment back stack and finish activity.
             case 0:
        fragment=new FragmentNewsFeed();
                    break;

             case 1:
        fragment = new FragmentMessages();
        break;

            default:
        break;
    }

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
    frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    listView_drawer.setItemChecked(possition, true);
    setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView_drawer);

}
```

In FragmentNewsFeed class,

```
public class FragmentNewsFeed extends Fragment 
{


   public FragmentNewsFeed()
   {

   }
  
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feeds, container,false);
      return view;
   }
       }
```

Whereas you can find content frame in a layout/activity_main.xml,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffff"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In R.layout.fragment_news_feeds,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear_Parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#008B8B"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.30"
    android:background="#2F4F4F"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_OwnItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```